# Can I use admob to Show Ads on Webgl to publish on Facebook games

Tags: admob, unity-webgl, facebook-gameroom

I I'm new to unity. I've created a game and want
publish on Facebook. I am confused, can i
implement admob plugin in unity for Facebook.
Will it this happen same way as i had
implemented to show ads on android.